# Is there a way to integrate an arbitrary build command to a Cargo build?

Tags: rust-cargo, rust-wasm

At the end of a cargo build, I would like to call `wasm-opt` with specific [optimization options](https://github.com/webassembly/binaryen) on the generated WASM file.
Unfortunately, it seems that the Cargo.toml does not support support [asyncify](https://web.dev/asyncify/) options.

A good solution would prevent cargo from rebuilding the project after running wasm-opt on the WASM file.

If I used a cargo-build script, it [is unclear to me how I could  specify a dependency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#change-detection) on the wasm-opt build step to avoid unnecessary re-builds even though the Rust source files haven't changed. Any pointers ?